# Kommasetzung – In diesem Beispiel Komma vor "und"?

Tags: conjunction, comma

Wird folgendes Komma (das in Klammern) gesetzt:

> Ich denke, dass das nicht so funktioniert(,) und vermute, dass man es deswegen irgendwie anders machen muss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ja, das fragliche Komma wird gesetzt. Siehe hierzu den Duden:

> Das **schließende** Komma eines vorangehenden Einschubs oder Nebensatzes o. Ä. bleibt erhalten <§ 72 E1>. (Vgl. auch Regel 116.)
>   Wir hoffen, dass wir Ihre Bedenken hiermit zerstreut haben, und grüßen Sie ...

Das Komma steht also weniger vor dem *und* als vielmehr nach dem *haben*.